# how to get image back after closing my app

Tags: android, parse-platform, bitmap, sharedpreferences

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
}

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        String struser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();
        iv = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button1 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);
            }


        });
        TextView txtUser = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
        txtUser.setText(struser);

            logout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.Logout);

            logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());                            // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Logout!");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Do you want to logout with your account ? ")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
                                                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                                        NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                                        if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {

                                            ParseUser.logOut();
                                            getActivity().finish();

                                        } else {

                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();

                    }
            });

    }


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
        case SELECTED_PICTURE :
            if (requestCode == SELECTED_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[]projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int  columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Bitmap YourSelectedImage= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(YourSelectedImage);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(filePath));

                }


            }
            break;
            default:
                break;
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: You need to use some storage for saving...  Obviously you can use sharedproperties for save the image path...  But such image can be deleted...  of course you can copy image to app's internal storage and save it path...  You can also save image in parse as you use it...

Comment: And your question...?